# jQuery .val() returning undefinded

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

a new developer here, was trying to extract the value using a html id `staffno` using jQuery

```
<div class="span3">
    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StaffNumber, new { id = "staffno" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffNumber)
        <span id="useravailabity"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

the js:

```
function GetId() {
    alert("Staff Id is " + $("#staffno").val());
}
```

I cannot figure out why is it returning me `undefined`??

Comment: It's hard to use to help you, we need to see when you run the alert and also it can be help full if you provide the compiled html code

Comment: The implication is that there is either no element matching `#staffno`, or there are multiple (which is invalid) and the first matched element has no `value` attribute to be read. Without seeing the actual HTML or a working example of the issue we can't offer any useful help.

Comment: please check the HTML from browser. Is it creating input control with id="staffno"

Comment: @AmitVerma it is creating an input control with StaffNumber

Comment: if creating control with id="StaffNumber " (although I have doubt on this as you have mentioned id in code) then you jquery $("#staffno").val() will never work. As it is searching control with id=staffno.

Comment: @AmitVerma it was creating a control with id="StaffNumber"

Comment: @Larrylicious then you jquery code should be alert("Staff Id is " + $("#StaffNumber").val())

Comment: @AmitVerma I have changed to what you have mentioned and it works successfully, thank you so much!

Comment: @Larrylicious if that was useful then please vote the comment as useful so that it can help other developers.

Comment: @AmitVerma how do i vote the comment as useful? I am new here, still trying to understand the functionalities here

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StaffNumber, new { id = "staffno" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffNumber)
```

Jquery will not extract anything cause it treats content without html tags as simple text

Comment: These are ASP.Net MVC controls which will be rendered as HTML.

Comment: Is there a way that I can extract the value out?

Comment: may i know why is it so? @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the solution to this question.

```
   <div class="span3">
            <div class="control-group">

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StaffNumber, new { id = "staffno" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffNumber)
                <span id="useravailabity"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The Html.EditorFor had created the control with id = "StaffNumber". All I had done was to change

```
 alert("Staff Id is " + $("#staffno").val());
```

to this:

```
 alert("Staff Id is " + $("#StaffNumber").val());
```

Thank you guys for helping me out to understand how jQuery and ASP.Net Mvc Controls work! Much appreciated!